# Лицензии на Программное Обеспечение

Tags: лицензирование

Я хочу узнать у знатоков лицензирования, какая больше из лицензий подходит для моей библиотеки. Я опишу что хочу:

- У библиотеки открытый исходный код, можно изменять ее как душе угодно.
- Изменения должны быть открытыми для сообщества.
- Можно использовать комерчески и в проприентарном по(можно статически и динамически линковать).

С уважением.

Comment: скорее всего подойдет одна из GNU вернее GPL, так же можно посмотреть на этом сайте: https://choosealicense.com/ по описанию можно понять подходит лицензия под твои требования или нет

Comment: GPL требует что бы линкованный коде тоже был GPL

Answer (score 2):

Похоже на LGPL и CDDL лицензию. Для сравнения разных лицензий можно посмотреть [тут](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/) или [тут](https://opensource.org/licenses/category).